# ObjectContext.SaveChanges() violates primary key, throws UpdateException?

Tags: .net, primary-key, entity, savechanges, objectcontext

Paraphrasing from [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283139.aspx) ...

> An INSERT statement is generated by
>   the Entity Framework and executed on
>   the data source when SaveChanges is
>   called on the ObjectContext.
>
> If the INSERT operation succeeds,
>   server-generated values are written
>   back to the ObjectStateEntry. When
>   AcceptChanges is called automatically
>   at the end of the SaveChanges
>   execution, a permanent EntityKey is
>   computed by using the new
>   server-generated values.

This does not seem to be occurring in my code. When I call `ObjectContext.SaveChanges()`, an `UpdateException` is thrown with `InnerException.Message` value:

> **"duplicate key value violates unique constraint student_term_data_pkey"**

Here is the offending code:

```
using (DataAccessLayerEntities context = new DataAccessLayerEntities()) {
     StudentTermData mostCurrent = new StudentTermData() {
          // Foreign keys:    
          StudentId = studentId,
          TermId = currentTerm.Id,

          // Non-nullable properties:
          SponsorCode = string.Empty,
          AdmissionNumber = string.Empty,
          Expiration = string.Empty
     };

     context.StudentTermDatas.AddObject(mostCurrent);
     context.SaveChanges();  // UpdateException occurs here.
}
```

I have verified that `StudentTermData.Id` is marked as an EntityKey in my Entity data model. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Can you should the DDL for StudentTermData, in particular the Id field, is it actually being generated on the server?

Comment: Any reason you are using the Id fields and adding the StudentTermData to the objectContext manually instead of simply doing `mostCurrent.Students.Add(student)` and `mostCurrent.Term = currentTerm` after creating an instance of it?  (Assuming you can use a single objectContext to load them and apply them)

Comment: The student ID is obtained as-is from the SelectedValue of a ComboBox, which isn't bound to a collection of Students, so that's why I don't use mostCurrent.Students.Add(student). Also, the term is passed as an argument to the function after being loaded by a separate ObjectContext.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean in your first comment. Do you want the schema for student_term_data? Or just the INSERT query that gets generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was caused by a bug in EF4 where the EF designer doesn't set the StoreGeneratedPattern attribute in the SSDL. The problem is documented in [this blog](http://geeksharp.com/2010/05/27/ef4-bug-in-storegeneratedpattern-ssdl/) and [this Microsoft Connect ticket](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/505178/storegeneratedpattern-property-in-ado-net-entity-model-designer-sets-cdsl-annotation-but-not-ssdl-attribute).

The solution was to open my model's .edml file in a text editor, locate the `<EntityType Name="student_term_data">` XML tag, and add `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` to the property tag being used as an EntityKey:

```
  <EntityType Name="student_term_data">
     <Key><PropertyRef Name="id" /></Key>
     <Property Name="id" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
     ...
  </EntityType>
```

I then re-opened my model in the EF designer, made a small change (moved an entity position) and saved. This caused the code generator to run, presumably synchronizing the CDSL with the SSDL.

My code now runs as expected.

Comment: There is also another work-around listed on the Microsoft ticket that uses third-party "model comparer" software to synchronize the SSDL and CDSL, without having to manually modify XML.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

If you are trying to do an insert, then do not fill in the PK field (I'm guessing that's StudentID).

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. The primary key is simply titled Id, StudentId is a foreign key.